# Xcode - My app is acting weird

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have a project that I got handed me (half working / half not working) and I have never seen something like to this before.

I have a storyboard and one of the scenes is called 'CompletionVC' and inside that scene I have this:

[image]

and in my header file for this scene I have this:

```
UIPickerViewDataSource,UIAlertViewDelegate>
{

    IBOutlet UIButton *areaButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *unitButton;
    IBOutlet UIView *searchView;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *userLabel;
}
```

and none of those IBOutlets have any Referencing Outlets.

and in my .m file for this scene I have this:

```
- (IBAction)AreaButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
```

and this does not have a sentEvent assigned to it.

But somehow they are still appearing in my app, which is fine, but I want to adjust them and I cant find them anywhere....based off the information I provided, can someone give me a tip or two about where I these IBOutlets? I would like to make some adjustments, but I can't find them anywhere...also sometimes these IBOutlets have a Sent Event and Referencing Outlet, but it was referencing a file that is not there. The IBOutlets appear and are functional...weird eh?

[image]

Comment: (1) The views might be in your storyboard/XIB file without being connected to any outlets/actions.  (2) The outlets/actions could be created programmatically.  (3) The views could be created programmatically.  Try setting a breakpoint on `areaButton`, for example, run your app, and the breakpoint will pause execution when it is referenced.

Comment: I added a breakpoint on `-(IBAction)AreaButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender` and my results are in my question (the photo)

Comment: grrr...for some reason I cant add an image, but I see self = (LHCompletionVC *) and sender = (UIButton *) how would I find out where they are coming from?

Comment: Search your code base for `action:@selector(AreaButtonPressed:)`.  If it's not there, it's in Interface Builder.

Comment: I did a search for `action:@selector(AreaButtonPressed:)` and I did not find it, Its also not in my Interface Builder